# Injecting Doctrine entity manager in service in order to implement a quick notifier service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to symfony 2, going through the documentation and I'm struggling to create a notification service to notify a list of users about some updates ( the user entity is on OneToMany relation with notification entity, just to make it clear)

This is the service class:

```
<?php

namespace OC\UserBundle\Services;
use  OC\UserBundle\Entity\Notification;
use  Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager as EntityManager;

class Notificateur
{

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function notifier($text, $users)
  {
      foreach ($users as $user)
      {
          $notification=new Notification();
          $notification->setDate(new \DateTime());
          $notification->setText($text);
          $notification->setStatus('1');
          $notification->setUser($user);
          $this->em->persist($notification);
      }
          $this->em->flush();
  }
}
```

this is how I defined my service in service.yml inside my bundle:

```
services
    notificateur:
        class: OC\UserBundle\Services\Notificateur
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

and this is the action inside my controller ( this is for test only, to notify the current user:

```
public function notifAction() {

        $user=$this->getUser();
        $notificateur=$this->get('notificateur');
        $notificateur->notifier('your account is updated',$user);
        Return new Response('OK');
    }
```

when I execute app/console debug:container I can see my service there but nothing is persisted to the database.
I don't know what I'm missing, I would be grateful if you could help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

In notifAction you're passing a single user from $this->getUser();

```
$notificateur->notifier('your account is updated',$user);
```

In your service you're traversing an array of users, not a single user. If you wanted to just do a single user this would work:

```
public function notifier($text, $user) {

    $notification=new Notification();
    $notification->setDate(new \DateTime());
    $notification->setText($text);
    $notification->setStatus('1');
    $notification->setUser($user);
    $this->em->persist($notification);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you Richard, this worked when I removed the foreach loop, but my goal is to notify users who are subscribed to a particular event.
I can't understand this: 
the notifier() function gets a list of users as second argument and for each user on that list it should execute the above instructions. Isn't this supposed to work even when I call the function inside my controller and pass a single user ( As I understand , the function will treat him as a single element of the list) ?!!??

Comment: You already got it below :) But yes if you pass an array to a function, you get an array, in the original issue a single scalar variable being passed - not array so not iterable. Another option would be to require an array of users passed with a guard clause on the parameter like is_array()

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this. This was a php issue,

I created an array in the notifier() function and added the current user to it:

```
public function notifAction() {

        $user=$this->getUser();
        $users = array();
        array_push($users, $user);
        $notificateur=$this->get('notificateur');
        $notificateur->notifier('your account is updated',$users);
        Return new Response('OK');
}
```

This was just to test if it works, but the main goal is to get the list of subscribed members to an event and notify them all, then these lines:

```
$user=$this->getUser();
$users = array();
array_push($users, $user);
```

would be replaced: with

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(.....)
$list_users=$repository->find(....)
//
//
//
$notificateur=$this->get('notificateur');
$notificateur->notifier('your account is updated',$list_users);
Return new Response('OK');
```

Hope this helps those who need to implement a quick notification system using symfony 2.